# Limits, Continuity and Differentiability - Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, continuity

1) Can I take the limit of a function $f(z)$ defined on $D$, with $z\to z_0$ where $z_0\notin D$?

2) A function is continuous at $z_0$ when $\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z) = f(z_0)$. Then can a function be continuous at $z_0$ if $z_0 \notin D$?

3) If a function is not continuous in $z_0$, can it still be differentiable in $z_0$? In general, does a function have to be defined at $z_0$ to be continuous and/or differentiable?

Thank you

Comment: What do you think? If $D$ is the domain of $f$, does $f(z_0)$ exists for $z_0\notin D$?

Comment: Is $z_0$ on the border of $D$?

Comment: Oh right, so it doesn't exist for $z_0\notin D$, so the function cannot be continuous there? What about the limit and differentiability though?

Comment: I was thinking about $D$ as a punctured disk say, say of radius $a$, so that we have $0<|z-z_0|<a$. But yeah could be on the border as well! I just want to try to understand the behaviour of limits, continuity and differentiability in all cases in which the function is not defined there!

Comment: Try [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=differentiability%20at%20a%20hole)?

Comment: But my question is specific for complex analysis, cause it seems like weird things can happen with complex function, so I don't want a Real answer.

Comment: How do you define $f(z_0)$?

Comment: If $z_0\notin D$ as above, then I don't know how to define $f(z_0)$, as $f$ is not defined there, so $f(z_0)$ should not exist. However for a general $z_1 \in D$ I define it as $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to S\subseteq\mathbb{C}, (x,y)\longmapsto z:= x+iy$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z_0 \in \overline D$ (for instance the center of a punctured disk on which $f$ is defined) then you can talk about $\lim_{z \to z_0}f(z)$ because we would like that the quantity $|z-z_0|$ can get arbitrarily small for certain $z$'s in $D$. However, you can talk neither about continuity nor about differentiability because for that you need  $f(z_0)$ to be defined.

If $z_0\notin \overline D$, then you can (but it doesn't make sense) to talk about $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)$. By definition, we have $\lim_{z \to z_0}f(z) = L$ if and only if:

$$(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall z \in D: |z-z_0|<\delta \implies |f(z)-L|<\epsilon)$$

One can say that if $\delta = d(z_0,D):=\inf_{z\in D} |z-z_0|$ (from metric topology, this is $>0$), then the implication is vacuously true for any $L$, so any $L \in \Bbb C$ equals $\lim_{z \to z_0}f(z)$. As you can see, this is not a very nice thing to have.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense! So evaluating that limit is possible, but would not make much sense as we could assign an arbitrary $L\in \mathbb{C}$ as the value of the function as $z\to z_0$ ? And what about differentiability? Does the function have to be defined at $z_0$ or continuous at $z_0$, in order to be differentiable there?

Comment: @Euler_Salter just by looking at the definitions of continuity and differentiability you can see that we need $f(z_0)$ to be well-defined. If $z_0 \notin D$, you can't talk about any of the two.

Comment: Oh right! Cause $f$ is differentiable at $z_0$ only if $f'(z_0) = \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$, so if $f$ is not well-defined at $z_0$, then we cannot have the numerator $f(z) - f(z_0)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Euler_Salter yes, but to be precise: $f$ is differentiable at $z_0$ if the limit $\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ exists.